# Vue Global Filter throws error of value undefined

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, filter

I am trying to format money. For this, I am using global filter like this:

```js
Vue.filter('formatMoney', (val) => {
  if (!value) return ''
  val = val.toString()
  return val.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    price: 1000
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ price | formatMoney }}</p>
</div>
```

However, I get this error called `value undefined`! But surprisingly, it works with local filter:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    price: 1000
  },
  filters: {
    formatMoney(val) {
      return val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ price | formatMoney }}</p>
</div>
```

How do I make this global filter work?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ahutL91m/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong argument name (`value`) in your global filter.
It should be `val`:

```
Vue.filter('formatMoney', (val) => {
  if (!val) return ''; // <--- value -> val
  val = val.toString()
  return val.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
})
```